# How can I create a flex row with gutters in IE?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a flexbox row with two columns. HTML is like this

```
<div class="flex-row">
<div class="col col-38 grey">
<div class="text">
    <h2>Headline
    </h2>
    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui  officia.
    </p>
    <button>Contact
    </button>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col col-62">
</div>
```

and the css

```
.home-flex-row{
margin:5px -5px 5px !important;
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
align-items:stretch;
 }

 .col {
margin:5px;
min-height:560px;
 }

 @media(max-width:991px){

.col{
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
 }

 @media(min-width:992px){
.col-38{
    flex-basis:calc(38% - 10px);
}

.col-62{
    flex-basis:calc(62% - 10px);

}
 }

 .col-62{
background:url(http://...);
background-size:cover;
 }

 .grey{
background:#e6e6e6;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
text-align:center;
padding:80px;

 }

 .text{
max-width:455px;

 }
```

This is working for Firefox and Chrome, but in IE 11 the cells are stacked and not in one row, and cell38 is actually larger then in Firefox and Chrome. How can I make it work for IE 11 as well?

Comment: I test your code with IE 11 and Chrome. I find that Output are similar but in IE 11 align-items: center which is applied to .grey class not giving any effect caused this issue. Testing result with IE 11: https://i.postimg.cc/cJsTv568/23.png You can test with any alternative property compatible with IE may help to solve the issue.

Comment: That's odd it is working for you because when I look at it with IE the columns are in seperate rows, for example the 38 and 62 columns are not on one line.

Comment: you can again try to make a test with the above code and let us know about the result.